# Two similar projects: one finds the CSS, other does not

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I have created two Netbeans projects and both have the same configuration in web.xml:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Both have the following directory structure for the css file:

```
<Root>\src\main\webapp\resources\css\styles.css
```

In a facelets template, in the `<h:head>` section both have

```html
<h:outputStylesheet name="styles.css" library="css" />
```

If I unzip their respective .war files, both have

```
<root>\resources\css\styles.css
```

When I launch these web apps and look at the web page thru firebug both use:

```
<root>javax.faces.resource/styles.css.xhtml
```

Now the BUT: one finds the css file and one does not. What am I missing here?

---

**Update**: As per the comments, I have checked the Net tab of Firebug of the project where the CSS fails. The CSS request/response is inside HTML tab instead of CSS tab and the response Header has `Content-Type: text/html;` and the response body is the entire web page rather than just the CSS like it is in the working project!

Request headers:

```
Host: mike-  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2  
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1  
Accept-Language: en-us  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate  
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7  
Connection: keep-alive  
Referer: http://mike-6:8080/root/  
Cookie: JSESSIONID=fa60fb0becd860721422cad79e09
```

Response headers:

```
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 Java/Sun Microsystems Inc./1.6), JSF/2.0  
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1  
Pragma: No-cache  
Cache-Control: no-cache  
Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 18:00:00 CST  
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked  
Date: Mon, 19 Sep 2011 03:06:22 GMT
```

Response body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/MyBills/javax.faces.resource/themes/sam/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;amp;v=3.0.M2" />  
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/MyBills/javax.faces.resource/styles.css.xhtml?ln=css" />  
</head>  
   <body>  
           /* body is entire web page */  
   </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Please elaborate "one finds the CSS file and one does not" in more technical detail. Does it return HTTP 404? Or does it return HTTP 2nn/3nn with unexpected content? Or does it return fine, but it don't get applied?

Comment: Both return the web page, but one implements the css and one does not. When I look in firebug, it shows me the css on the correct one, but on the other it say "There are no rules.  You can create one"

Comment: More technical please. Does it return 404? Or 2nn/3nn? With what content? Exactly as I asked before. If you don't understand my questions, please just say so instead of giving different/incomplete answers.

Comment: I see input fields and command buttons, so no 404.  I can input into the input fields and get results.  I do not understand 2nn/3nn.

Comment: On the successful one the footer section has a background color of green (css found).  On the unsuccessful one, the background color is white.

Comment: I mean, the CSS file, not the HTML page. Check *Net* tab in Firebug. Therein you can see response status and body for all resource requests. 404 and 2nn/3nn are just HTTP status codes (are you new in web development? learn HTTP asap, it's so crucial). E.g. 200 = successful, 304 = cached and not modified, 404 = resource not found.

Comment: You need to go to your server directory and check if the CSS file is there or not

Comment: @BalusC In the one that works, there are several requests in the NET/HTML and  
several request in the NET/CSS tabs of firebug including a 
    `GET styles.css.xhtml ln=css` 
in the CSS tab.  
All requests are `200 OK`.
In the one that does not work ALL requests are ONLY in the NET/HTML tab including the 
above GET with nothing in the CSS tab.  All requests in the HTML tab are 200 OK

Comment: This indicates that CSS files are served as HTML instead of as CSS. What is the response header and response body of the CSS file which is incorrectly in the Net/HTML tab? Click the entry to expand those details.

Comment: Thank you for the detail.This is really strange. I however recall having seen similar questions before about not-working CSS in PrimeFaces projects. Can you try creating a simple page without any `<p:xxx>` component and see if your CSS works. And then try adding a `<p:xxx>` component (maybe a random one or the same one as you used in your page where it failed) to the page and see if it indeed instantly breaks. Or if you don't have much `<p:xxx>` components in your page, remove them all -just for test.

Comment: @mlb1141: try seeing the output in the browser on this link, is it the css file or the html file ? http://host:port/webapp/javax.faces.resource/styles.css.xhtml?ln=css